# SNMP table with objects as columns AgentX subagent

Tags: net-snmp, mib, snmpd

I have a table in my MIB file in which some of the columns are not terminal values but intermediate object-identifiers.
I can't find documentation about how to manage this case in the AgentX NET-SNMP subagent (with the C libraries)

Visually, what I mean:

```
Row:  +------+------+--------+
      |      |      |        |
     val1   val2   object   val3
                    |
             -------+-------
             |      |      |
            val    val    val
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure, but mib2c can generate scalar and non-scalar mib handlers on the same MIB file, and then use generated files to make up the whole mib tree.